# Internet Explorer 11 Change the downloaded file name, replacing all the dots (.) with underscores (_)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Recently I've encounter this problem, each file I try to download with Internet Explorer 11, getting it's name changed automatically, by replacing the dot (.) in the file name to underscore (_). For example if I try to download `filename.exe` it will be changed to `filename_exe`.

This problem happen on any file I try to download, and from any website.
I try to do these steps to solve this issue (none of them worked for me): 
1. IE >> Internet options >> Security >> Enable Protected Mode >> DISABLE 
2. IE >> Internet options >> Security >> (for zones: Internet, Local internet and Trusted sites) >> Custom Level >> Miscellaneous >> Enable MIME Sniffing >> ENABLE 
3. IE >> Internet options >> Advanced >> Security >> Do Not save encrypted pages to disk >> DISABLE 
4. Restart to Internet Explorer 
5. Run Internet Explorer in "No Ad-ons" mode 
6. Run Windows update (I'm working on windows 7). 
None of the above solve my issue.

Side Note:
In addition I'm working on Virtual Machine (VM) that are running Automation tests. Each Night I run 50 automation tests on 50 VMs. And each Night between 1 to 3 VMs (different ones each night) failed the test that need to download a file, due to this issue. Only after restarting this VMs they return to downloading files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the "Restrict File Download" policies:

Source: [Event 1028 - Automatic Download Blocking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565669(v=vs.85).aspx)

- Open Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`):
- Expand Computer Configuration and disable any policies under:
  Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Internet Explorer >> Security Features >> Restrict File Download
- Expand User Configuration and disable any policies under:
  Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Internet Explorer >> Security Features >> Restrict File Download

Also, check the following registry paths for a DWORD value `iexplore.exe`.  Change the value to `0` or delete the value:

- HKLM >> Software >> Microsoft >>Internet Explorer >> Main >> FeatureControl >> FEATURE_RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD
- HKCU >> Software >> Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main >> FeatureControl >> FEATURE_RESTRICT_FILEDOWNLOAD

Finally, ensure that the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" setting is not enabled for all users.  Add the DWORD value `BypassSSLNoCacheCheck` and set to `1` under the following registry keys:

- HKLM >> SOFTWARE >> Microsoft >> Windows >> CurrentVersion >> Internet Settings
- HKCU >> SOFTWARE >> Microsoft >> Windows >> CurrentVersion >> Internet Settings

Comment: This solution fixed my problem. In the registry path, on 64 bit machine, the path is ... >> SOFTWARE >> Wow6432Node >> Microsoft >> ...

Comment: This worked for me too. Not sure which one is the exact fix but it corrected the issue in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for Windows 10

Go to control panel, programs and features, Turn Windows features on or off,
deselect IE11 and restart the machine. Go back and check it again to add. Restart and test if it's still changing the file extension.